# Antd Radio Button required in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, radio-button, antd

I am using antd in react. And I have created some radio inside radio.group. I want to make it required field on submitting the form.

```
 <Radio.Group onChange={onChange} value={value}>
      <Radio value={1}>A</Radio>
      <Radio value={2}>B</Radio>
      <Radio value={3}>C</Radio>
      <Radio value={4}>D</Radio>
    </Radio.Group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap all JSX with a Form component and you need to add a Button component within the same Form. Also you need to add Form.Item with properties to making Radio buttons required. So your code should look like this:

```js
      <Form>
        <Form.Item
          label="radio"
          name="radio"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please select an option!" }]}
        >
          <Radio.Group>
            <Radio value={1}>A</Radio>
            <Radio value={2}>B</Radio>
            <Radio value={3}>C</Radio>
            <Radio value={4}>D</Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
        </Form.Item>
        <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
```

### *P.S.: label and name properties in the Form.Item component are crucial to make the form item required.*